# javascript arrow function has undefined argument passed, how does this work?

Tags: javascript, arguments, undefined, arrow-functions

I am confused with the following snippet:

```
  let counted = countBy(text, char => {
      let script = characterScript(char.codePointAt(0));
      return script ? script.direction : "none";
  }).filter(({name}) => name != "none");
```

variable char gets defined inside the countBy function: I was trying to separate the arrow functions into separate functions so I can understand the code, but the variable char comes in the way.

I tried to separate the code so arrow functions were standalone functions, because I find the construct very confusing.

// here are the 2 functions in full: I am new to JS :-(

```
function dominantDirection(text) {
    let counted = countBy(text, char => {
        let script = characterScript(char.codePointAt(0));
        return script ? script.direction : "none";
  }).filter(({name}) => name != "none");

    if (counted.length == 0) return "ltr";

    return counted.reduce((a, b) => a.count > b.count ? a : b).name;
}
function countBy(items, groupName) {
      let counts = [];
      for (let item of items) {
          let name = groupName(item);
          let known = counts.findIndex(c => c.name == name);
          if (known == -1) {
              counts.push({name, count: 1});
          } else {
              counts[known].count++;
       }
     }
     return counts;
}
```

Comment: Q: Out of curiosity, exactly what is "dominantDirection()" supposed to do?  What's an example "text"?

Comment: *”variable char gets defined inside the countBy function”* — No. `char => { ... }` defines a function which takes one argument (`char`). You’re passing a function—called a callback—to `countBy`.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt response, actually I was trying to understand a example in Eloquent JS book by Marijn Haverbeke, chapter 5 higher order functions, final example, was so complex, essentially give an array of script objects, with an attribute called: direction, another called ranges, which in turn is a 2 array of utf code from and to pairs, given a string of characters determin the dominant direction of the characters in the script. Obviously Marijn's book should not have been the first one I picked up, thanks again. I will explain my confusion a bit more down below.

Answer (score 2):

Your `countBy` function receives two things:

1. An array of `items`
2. Another function that is called with every `item` in `items`, returning for each item its corresponding group name. The name of that other function within `countBy` is `groupName`, that's why it's invoked with `groupName(item)`.

So your `dominantDirection` function receives a `text` and counts characters by direction, using an anonymous function that receives a character and does its logic with it (that's the function that `countBy` will call `groupName`).  Maybe a more clear way of putting it would be:

```
const getDirection = char => { // This line could also have been: function getDirection(char) {
  let script = characterScript(char.codePointAt(0));
  return script ? script.direction : "none";
}

function dominantDirection(text) {
    let counted = countBy(text, getDirection).filter(({name}) => name != "none");

    if (counted.length == 0) return "ltr";

    return counted.reduce((a, b) => a.count > b.count ? a : b).name;
}
```

I hope that helps clear out the confusion a bit, feel free to ask if it's still not clear!

Btw if you want to read more about arrow functions, check the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: lipusal sir thanks! I see one thing in your snippet: in this line: let counted = countBy(text, getDirection).filter(({name}) => name != "none"); getDirection is being mentioned without the char parameter it expects, why is that okay? I was trying to do exactly what you did, but my line read: let counted = countBy(text, getDirection(char)).filter(({name}) => name != "none"); and char was not recognized in the function dominantDirection(text). Hope you understand my question. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, the lack of the `char` is intentional. What my snippet does is pass the _function_ as an argument, so `countBy` can call it. When you type `getDirection(char)` you are calling the function yourself, and passing the *result* of the function to `groupBy`, when what you want is to pass the function itself. Char is not recognized because you don't have a variable with that name. It's the same thing as doing `let counted = countBy(text, getDirection('a'))`. You don't want to pass the direction of a single character, you want the _function_ that gives you the direction for any character.

Answer (score 0):

You never answered my question about what ""dominantDirection()" is supposed to do.

I found the answer here:

> https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/reading-eloquent-javascript-can-i-ever-get-this-good/181511
>
> ... a program to take a string and identify what percentage of
>   whatever Unicode scripts are present in it out of the total. the
>   program also accounts for Unicode characters which take up more than
>   one code unit

Here's some very useful advice from the same thread:

> That book ([Eloquent Javascript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593272820)) is not for everyone, including me :wink: and many others too
>   don’t like it…
>
> A Better and Practical alternative for Eloquent Javascript is [The
>   Javascript Way](https://github.com/bpesquet/thejsway) followed by
>   [Programming for the Web with
>   JavaScript](https://www.edx.org/course/programming-web-javascript-pennx-sd4x).

Regarding your initial question, I hope lipusal's most excellent post gave you the answer you were looking for.  In particular, these two snippets are basically equivalent:

```
// "Classic" JS syntax:
countBy(text, function(char) {
      var script = characterScript(char.codePointAt(0));
      return script ? script.direction : "none";
});
```

vs.

```
// ES6 syntax:
countBy(text, char => {
      let script = characterScript(char.codePointAt(0));
      return script ? script.direction : "none";
});
```

PS:

From Amazon.com:

[Alright, but NOT a good book if you're just starting to learn JavaScript](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1ZCGRCI42K17S/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=1593275846)

and

[not for beginners](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R32UODHNA76JZT/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=1593279507)

Comment: Thanks again paulsm4 sir for your deep analysis. Yes, too many arrow functions too early in the book, I will look at the other books. Thanks!

Comment: DominantDirection actually returns the direction (ltr, rtl, etc) of all of the scripts in the JavaScript object the author includes in the book.  That freecodecamp book is worth a read but I'm not sure it tells the whole story, nor do I think this is an answer to the original question.